# Uncooked Pickled Fish: Can I recook it?

Tags: food-safety, fish, pickling

I made pickled salmon a few days ago.  I clearly did not cook it enough before pickling it for four days in vinegar. It is basically raw and completely falling apart.

Can I recook it now by boiling it in its own pickling juice, or is that not a smart thing to do?

Comment: can you describe your pickling process?

Comment: I mixed vinegar, water and sugar. brought to a boil. dropped the fish in for less than a minute. Removed the fish. Poured the liquid on top and put in the fridge.

Comment: Do you have ratios on vinegar/sugar/water?

Comment: equal sugar and vingar. 2 cups of water, 1/4 cup each of vinegar and sugar.

Comment: You should change the title, "undercooked" instead of "uncooked". Anyway... this is a two part process, boiling (cook with heat) and then pickling (preserving in an acid brine). If you failed in the first step, then you cannot solve it with the preserving, or reboiling. It will be a different product, not pickled salmon.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't eat it as leaving it raw with such a weak pickling solutiong for multiple days is somewhat risky. A general rule for pickling solution should be 1:1 water to vinegar, and if your fish still seems completely raw the acid was not strong enough to denature any proteins on its own so I wouldn't trust its germ killing potential.

Comment: A bit more details in the answer would be helpful.http://www.cooksinfo.com/pickling suggests a minimum vinegar:water ratio of 1:1.